# How to import main package and all packages it requires at once in R

Tags: r, import

I am trying to import some packages using the `library()` function, but I keep getting error functions of the form

```
Error: package X required by package Y could not be found
```

I am then manually installing those dependencies, but it seems to keep going. Is there a way to import them all at once?

I did find another post with a similar issue but it seemed that it was focused on installing the  packages, instead of importing them afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```
install("package", dependencies = TRUE)
```

If you want to load many packages and not write library you can do

```
my.pack <- c("package1","package2","package3","package4")
#install.packages(my.pack)
lapply(my.pack, require, character.only = TRUE)
```

Comment: So the installation itself is being done via BiocManager which already downloads the dependencies.
As for the loading of packages, does this mean I need to know all the packages required and put them into a list? Is there not an easier way to load them?
If not, thanks for your help!

Comment: This is the only other solution i know of and it loads all packages lapply(.packages(all.available = TRUE), function(xx) library(xx,character.only = TRUE))